# Cannot Run a Simple SQL update query from Microsoft Access (error 3075)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to update multiple records from an another table. However, I'm receiving error 3075.

I've made sure there are no syntax error or misspells in my identifiers.

```
UPDATE Item

SET SupplierCost =  t1.List_Price

FROM Item INNER JOIN t1 ON Item.ItemNum = t1.Upc;
```

I expect a successful update to Item table. It will update the SupplierCost to List_Price if the ItemNum = Upc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks more like a sql server pattern. I think in access  the join goes after the update:

```
UPDATE Item INNER JOIN t1 ON Item.ItemNum = t1.Upc;

SET item.SupplierCost =  t1.List_Price
```

Don't forget you can use the query designer in access to create "query that updates another table"